# Artifact While Rendering 2D Data using OpenGL using Perspective Matrix

Tags: opengl

The line below, extending an infinite distance is the artifact. What is expected is a line that connects the two ellipses:

[image]

I have inspected the data that is loaded into the VBO manually and the points used to represent the line are at the center of the middle ellipse and at the center of the bottom ellipse. The code for drawing looks like.

```
m_shaderManager->useProgram(m_handle);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo); GL_CALL
m_shaderManager->enableVertexAttribArrays(m_handle, m_shaderVertexAttrib);
m_shaderManager->setUniformMatrix4X4(m_handle, m_mvp.to_gl_matrix(), "uMVP");
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, m_vertexAttrib.get_attribute_count()); GL_CALL
```

1. The call to get_attribute_count() returns 2 as expected.
2. The m_mvp is the identity matrix.

My question is not where is the problem in the code. There is a lot of code to sieve through. Rather, my question is where should the debugging begin? I have drawn simple lines with this code before and I have inspected the raw data. What other types of things might cause this behavior?

---

As per request this is one place I am looking while debugging:
[image]
[image]

Comment: this looks like you are mixing some ui elements and openGL rendering. So far I do not understand what is drawn from opengl, and what is the overlay from the widgets. Where is the OpenGL viewport? Did you know that you do not need any projection matrix, if you do 2D rendering?

Comment: @KenSlade Took some screen shots.

Comment: @Arne If you use an orthorgarphic project you do not need a projection matrix. However I am allowing the user to zoom in and out. I feel the perspective matrix is better suited for this. Also I feel the image depicts the problem clearly enough.

Comment: Reason for the down vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell your `m_mvp` is the identity, so I guess the input in the vertex shader is the same to the output (at least the vertex positions). If your two points you put in the shader are the two vectors visible: `[0 0 0]` and `[3.5e-8, -3, 0]`, then it is no wonder that your output looks like how it is at the moment. `[0 0 0]` is the center of the screen, wher the line starts, and `[3.5e-8, -3, 0]` is outside of the screen by -2 in y direction (under the visible area). All visible vertices on screen are in the range `[-1 | 1]` in each dimension (normalized device coordinates).

Comment: Should of caught that. What i had forgot to do is take the transform of the spline and multiply it by the (proj * view) matrix.